# What is the experimental support behind taking electrons as a revolving particles in E.Rutherford model?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

From Rutherford we know that almost the entire mass and total positive charge in an atom are at the center of the atom and electrons in the atom revolve in orbit around this central core. But my question is **what did Rutherford see in his alpha particle scattering experiment for which he proposed electrons as a revolving one?**

Answer (score 1):

Through the particle scattering he deduced that proton were highly charged centers and there were electron around it. Now the basic logic that comes to mind is that those electron would collapse into the proton, just like our earth would collapse into sun if it stops revolving. so to Keep itself from collapsing into the proton, it was proposed that it rotates in circular orbit.

Comment: But my question is how Rutherford postulated this fact from his alpha particle scattering experiment. Because in his experiment he only saw that there is something in the center of an atom which scattered some alpha particles. And from this he only can say about the nucleus of an atom.

Comment: He knew the charge, positive against positive (alpha positive, repulsion in scatter) , and that the atoms are neutral, and that electrons come out of atoms